# When does the loading of data occur in Firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase

My data is sorted with date and an incremental ID as this:

- 20140622

  - value_1
  - value_2
- 20140623

  - value_3
  - value_4

In order to detect when a new date is added, I set an on('child_added') listener, and then another on('child_added') listener to detect new values within that date because on('child_added') is only triggered for immediate childs.

To avoid double bandwith usage and to make load faster, I'd like to know in which moment does the transfer of all the data of that snapshot occurs: immediately when I define the new child or when I use the .val() function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Data is downloaded when you establish a listener using on() or once() and remains cached locally and synced until all listeners are disconnected.

It's not generally necessary to also establish a `child_added` listener for the nested children, since they already exist in the data downloaded as part of the parent:

```
var ref = new Firebase(URL);
ref.on('child_added', function(snap) {
   console.log('parent rec', snap.name());
   snap.forEach(function(childSnap) {
      console.log('child rec', childSnap.name());
   });
});
```

However, there is also no harm in nested `child_added` events; this is all optimized internally by Firebase and those values will be returned immediately and from the locally cached data:

```
var ref = new Firebase(URL);
ref.on('child_added', function(snap) {
   console.log('parent rec', snap.name());
   snap.ref().on('child_added', function(snap) {
      console.log('child rec', snap.nam());
   });
});
```

The only caveat here is that if you want to call off() on those event listeners later, they must all be disconnected before the server connection will be severed and all cached data is purged.

Comment: Actually what I'm doing to avoid that issue with the off() call is to define two 'on' listeners, but not nested:
`fb1=new Firebase('https://XXX.firebaseio.com/20140623/');
fb2=new Firebase('https://XXX.firebaseio.com/20140623/value_3');`
Will this be also optimized by Firebase?

Comment: Also optimized. The data set is cached one time and used locally, applying deltas from server as needed.